# "Site can't be reached" when trying to query database from webapp page in IPSEC infrastructure

Tags: windows-server-2012, wireshark, ipsec, asp.net

things are like this:

1. VM with Windows Server 2012 for asp.net webapp - **APPServer**
2. VM with Windows Server 2012  for sql server database(different from 1 - but same network) - **DBServer**
3. *CLient1* - Another VM with Windows Server 2012 from which I access a webapp that is hosted on **APPServer**(different network than first 2)
4. *Client2* - Second Another VM with Windows Server 2012 from which I access a webapp that is hosted on **APPServer**(different network than first 3)
5. All 4 servers are in an IPSEC infrastructure

Now,

- From *CLient1* I access the webapp from Chrome -> log in -> navigate to some Report page -> generate report => "Site can't be reached"
- Same thing From *CLient2* I access the webapp from Chrome -> log in -> navigate to some Report page -> generate report => Report is generated and showed

I've installed Wireshark and on **CLient2** when I hit generate Report button it only shows **ESP** results, on the other hand on **CLient1** when I hit generate Report button it shows a few **ESP** than this (between **APPServer** and **CLient1**):

- ISAKMP 246 Quick Mode
- ISAKMP 278 Quick Mode
- ISAKMP 102 Quick Mode
- ISAKMP 118 Quick Mode
- ISAKMP 166 Informational
- ISAKMP 166 Informational

then some **ESP* again

Comment: This sounds a bit like Client2 has already successfully established an ESP SA ("Quick Mode") earlier, so it can send ESP-encrypted data packets directly, but Client1 failed to establish one, so it's trying to negotiate one again on-demand -- and failing again. The "Informational" packets look suspiciously like the ones which cancel the pending SA.

Comment: What did you use to set up IPsec on Windows? (I think it has at least two completely separate clients...) Have you checked the corresponding log files, both on Client1 and on APPServer?

Comment: @user1686 if that would be true, won't mean that I couldn't even access the webapp at all?

Comment: @user1686 I've checked windows logs and indeed I see 2 "Audit Failure"(Keying Module Name: IKEv1 and AuthIP) -though I'm logged in app and I can navigate through pages